# How to save userRole in mongo....?

Tags: mongodb

can anyone tell me how can I store user role in mongo db either by a list of role with user document or I create  a new collection for user role in MongoDb ?

Comment: this generator has basic support for user roles - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: Mongodb stores its roles in admin.system.roles.  You can create custom roles using the createRole command, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/